# issue of scrolling in gridview (specifically in samsung phone)

Tags: android, android-gridview

[image]

Hello , I faceing issue in Gridview. and mostly in samsung phone.Sometimes icons are invisible when scrolled or leave lots of space upperside of screen. this all are happened when scroll the menu. please check screenshot.
gridviewadapter.java

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomepageGeSe>
{
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<HomepageGeSe> data = null;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    public GridviewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HomepageGeSe> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        HomepageGeSe list = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(list.getName());

        if(list.getDrawableId() != 0)
        {
            holder.txtTitle.setText(list.getName());
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(list.getDrawableId())
                    .fit ()
                    .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                    .into(holder.imageItem);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

Homepage.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id = "@+id/rootLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    gridview_row.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageDes">
            </ImageView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                android:textColor="@color/textview_all">
            </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```